# How to open Nuget package manager console in Rider

Tags: rider

I am trying to enable migration for code-first approach in rider but there is no option showing for the NuGet package manager console. Can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rider doesn't support the NuGet Package Manager Console, but it has support for EF6 migrations.

For additional info, please read this article:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/